# How to handle Domain Driven Design when domain is dynamic / changes

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

In order to make it clear what I mean, let us build a hypothetical scenario where this might be needed.

Let us say I am building some software for a company that manages whiskey breweries in Scotland. Each brewery company can have a copy of this software to manage all the business logistics.

Assume that I have a `Kettle` object, and on it we'll have some properties, e.g. `.Colour` and `.Material`.

But what if the Glenfiddich brewery wants another property on the domain? e.g. `.Size` and some other brewery doesn't care about all the above and is only interested in `.Content` and `.DateFermentationStarted`?

In OOP is there a way I can make my `Kettle` object dynamic (have different properties and methods) depending on some parameter named `Customer`?

If I'm not mistaken, this is very different from Polymorphsim.

Comment: Google for multi-tenant or multi-tenancy apps (where only users within a specific tenancy can use objects within that tenant). Look also at Vaughn Vernon' book called [Implementing Domain-Driven Design](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321834577/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_il_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=0321834577&linkCode=as2&tag=onehundredaco-20&linkId=R2A7NFYTIGIGRQ4K)

Comment: Thanks MaxS. A lot of the stuff returned by Google seems to suggest that I 'create different apps for each customer' .. is there really no better way? :/

Comment: A multi-tenant app allows you to target multiple types of breweries within the same app. Seems that google is not returning the right results ;-)

Comment: You might be missing a concept which is the abstraction that represent the definition of what a Kettle is (e.g. what properties it has). Now, this myriad of dynamic properties begs the question where the behavior is and why/how it's influenced by these dynamic properties. "Build-to-customer" is a smell of being in an immature domain or one you know little of. In any case, if you will want to scale this on the operational end as well (more deployments), you will need to dig for the common abstraction that still provides value to your customers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply much DDD in this scenario, because the Domain concepts definition change from one client to another. I mean we all have a Kettle but there can be of any property the client wants. How can you apply behaviour? More precisely on what?

At most your "domain" objects will be data structures. It does matter who gets a saying in defining objects and what the customizing options are. If for example, a client can choose from predefined properties then you have some room to maneuver.

But if they can add any property with any name, you're losing semantics and just end up with data structures made up of magic strings. And you can't enforce business rules, unless you also have a business rule editor that clients can use to define rules. And that would be quite complicated for both developer and client.

So, IMO, DDD is not really suitable for this unless you're building separate apps for each customer, but proper OOP still is. You'll be working with data structures though and probably an ORM will help here.

Comment: +1 for *"At most your "domain" objects will be data structures."*. It won't be possible to fully model this domain. Embrace this fact and make this schemaless nature an intrinsic part of your design.

Comment: I have to agree here.  @Ciwan, if those properties are purely informational then you can model that easily.  However, as soon as you require those different properties to be involved in behaviour you have a problem.  You will end up with either completely different models (physical code bases) per customer or some generic structure that ends up composing into a unique structure from a logical point-of-view per customer.  You will have to choose your poison here :)

Comment: Thanks guys. @EbenRoux the properties are purely informational in the sense that if customer A at a future date wishes to retrieve the information about a Kettle, it can get all the information back that it stored originally. So basically the Kettle input form would have different fields for different customers. How should I go about this? This is what I find difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If those properties are dynamic, you have several options.

1. to have a base class with common properties and then to derive new classes with defined new properties.
   This solution has a problem however - you have to create different build for each customer that needs special properties.
   The plus is that the system is fully documented in sense of explicit properties on code level.
2. To model **Property as a separate autonomus class** and to be able to create instances of properties and assign them to domain objects in run-time.
   Properties can be defined in DB (with their names, maybe data types) and assigned to certain domain classes that need then. This way there is no need to make new builds for each different configuration, only a DB update is necessary.

This simple class diagrams shows the idea:

[image]

Additional properties are defined in the DB and than in run-time read and assigned to domain object.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thank you for making me laugh for your brits examples :-D

What I would do, and keep in mind that I'm a beginner, is to have a Domain Object that handles all properties, and a derived type that provides also an interface to tell the tenant which properties are allowed for reading.

```
interface iKettle
{
    public getColour() : ?Colour;
}

interface iUserKettle extends iKettle
{
    public canReadColour() : bool;
}

class Kettle implements iKettle
{
    public getColour() : ?Colour
    {
        return this.colour;
    }
}

class UserKettle extends Kettle implements iUserKettle
{
    public UserKettle(....., UserKettleProperties props)
    {
        this.props = props;
    }

    public canReadColour() : bool
    {
        return this.props.canRead("colour");
    }

    public getColour() : ?Colour // override
    {
        if(this.canReadColour())
            return super.getColour();
        else
            throw new Exception("You aren't allowed to know the colour");
    }
}
```

The point of the canRead* methods is to have an explicit way to know if a property is readable or not.

Let's say you have a field of Kettle that returns a value and that is also nullable.
then you do instance.getSomeProperty() and you get NULL. But you got NULL because the value is actually NULL or because you aren't allowed to read it? That's the reason you have a second method that is canReadSomeProperty() that tells you if you are allowed to call the getter method.

Alternatively to have the canRead* methods and throwing exceptions you might consider to just return NULL or a null-object.

Comment: I'm glad you found the example scenario amusing :D What you are suggesting assumes that I fully know before hand what all the properties for all customers will be. This is not the case, at the admin panel (which I plan on having), a system administrator would want to say that **for customer Famous Grouse I require a Location property on the Kettle object**

Comment: Still, the "domain" exists and it is the Kettle. I'm editing my answer

Comment: but first a question: why do you want to limit properties for some customers? Can't you return NULL?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you just need user defined custom properties:

```
public class Kettle
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> CustomProperties;
}


var kettle = new Kettle();
kettle.CustomProperties["Size"] = "1";
kettle.CustomProperties["Content"] = "Some Content";
kettle.CustomProperties["DateFermentationStarted"] = "1/1/2014";
```

You can save those properties in a DB as key/value pairs for an individual customer. Then create a configuration GUI or XML configuration file to define the custom properties per installation. When you create a Kettle object in your system you'll also load up the custom properties from your repository of choice.

The challenge here is if the customer needs business logic attached to those properties. Since the properties are dynamic then the business logic would need to be dynamic as well (i.e plugins, scripting, etc.). And that gets into a whole different set of issues.